# Can't login to my account and as guest

Tags: ubuntu

Today I've updated Vivaldi and Opera on my Ubuntu 15.04. After reboot I can't login to my account and as guest.
It bounce me back to login screen again and again.

If i press CTRL+ALT+F1-F6 i get only black screen.

**Edit:**
If I log in as root in recorvery mode, it return me 0 in home. /home I have on other partition but in fstab everything is good (I think). And my /home isn't empty (I check from Live USB)

**Edit:**
If I log in as root in recorvery mode and use `mount -a` /home is working properly. It's something wrong with mount my /home on boot. But what?

What is going on? How to fix it? I need Ubuntu for work.

Comment: Did you tried clearing your cookies? or are you not talking about loging in on superuser?

Comment: @LPChip, OP is asking about ubuntu

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about Ubuntu. If I log in as root in recorvery mode, it return me 0 in home. /home I have on other partition but in fstab everything is good (I think). And my /home isn't empty (I check from Live USB).

Comment: You might want to edit your post and make that more clear. The more information you can provide, including steps you have tried, the less of a puzzle it becomes and the easier we can help you.

Comment: @LPChip, I've added new info. Sorry, I'm a little nervous cuz I need Ubuntu for work.